# Datavserse Relationships from SQL

Tags: sql, powerapps, dataverse

If I want to import sql data into dataverse tables how can I import data from 2 exist sql tables and map the relationship with a primary key / foreign key relationship?

When I tried this, I didn't get an option to select the pk/fk to map and the relationship in the lookup returned no results for the existing data. How do we know what keys are being used for the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know the type of relationships been used in dataverse, As dataverse itself has sql database as backend. [Types of table relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/create-edit-entity-relationships#types-of-table-relationships)

Now for example, you wish to import contacts into dataverse and that contact has parent (N:1) Account related to it.

You will first need to have that Account record already in dataverse.
If it is not available you will import/create Account Record.

If Account record is already available you will need to get Guid of that account record.
Once you have the Guid, in contact table you will `parentcustomerid` field and you should set this field with Type of table i.e. account and it's Guid.

[check this forum especially comment section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/754031/adf-mapping-data-flow-sink-to-dataverse-lookup-fie.html)

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Comment: did you managed to solve this?